# Consume UserControl in FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, flowdocument

I am trying to create a UserControl that will be re-used to display similar sets of data like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UtilitiesForSageHRMS.Print.CalculateReport_DetailLine"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UtilitiesForSageHRMS.Print"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Name="LayoutGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="86"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="CalculateFieldLabel"
                   Tag="{Binding}"
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock Name="CalculateFieldValue"
                   Text="{Binding}"
                   TextAlignment="Right"
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I would like to use this in a FlowDocument as follows:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:p="clr-namespace:UtilitiesForSageHRMS.Print;assembly=UtilitiesForSageHRMS">


        <FlowDocument.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="/DelphiaLibrary;component/Dictionary/StylesDictionary.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </FlowDocument.Resources>

        <Section FontFamily="Verdana"
                 FontSize="11">
            <BlockUIContainer>

                <StackPanel>

                    <p:CalculateReport_DetailLine DataContext="{Binding OrderedPercent}"
                                                  Indent="10"
                                                  CollapseIfZero="True"
                                                  FieldLabel="Ordered Percent" />
                </StackPanel>

            </BlockUIContainer>
        </Section>

    </FlowDocument>
```

`Indent`, `CollapseIfZero`, etc. are properties defined in the code-behind of the UserControl.

I create the FlowDocument using the following method:

```
public static FlowDocument RenderFlowDocumentTemplateFromXAML(String xaml, object dataContextObject)
{
    //Use the XAML reader to create a FlowDocument from the XAML string.
    FlowDocument document = XamlReader.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xaml))) as FlowDocument;
    if (dataContextObject != null)
    {
        document.DataContext = dataContextObject;
    }

    // from http://www.bradcurtis.com/document-and-report-generation-using-xaml-wpf-data-binding-and-xps/
    // we need to give the binding infrastructure a push as we are operating outside of the intended use of WPF
    if (dataContextObject != null)
    {
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        dispatcher.Invoke(
           DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
           new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate { return null; }),
           null);
    }
    return document;
}
```

When I get to the first line of the method (`FlowDocument _document = ...`), I get this error:

> XamlObjectWriterException: 'Cannot create unknown type
>   '{clr-namespace:UtilitiesForSageHRMS.Print;assembly=UtilitiesForSageHRMS}CalculateReport_DetailLine'.'

I have tried various solutions I have found on Google but none of them make any difference, I get the same error message.  Is it just not possible to do what I am trying in a `FlowDocument`

**NOTE** The files for the FlowDocument and UserControl are stored as Resources and their `Build Action` are all set to `Embedded Resource`, as I do not want to have a number of files installed (I have a lot of these flow documents)